# Why is tensoring a functor? On objects, it is only defined up to isomorphism... also fiber products...

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, tensor-products

My complaint is mainly that the tensor product is only defined up to isomorphism, but a functor needs to send objects to objects, not just to isomorphism classes.

My guess would be that this is resolved in principal because there is such a canonical way of constructing the tensor product (as certain formal symbols, modulo some equivalence relations), and this satisfies me at least in the category of rings or modules. However, I am really asking this question because I am trying to understand fiber products of schemes better, and I would like to say something like $X  \times _Z \_$ is a functor on the category of $Z$ schemes...

but I am not sure that this makes sense, because now there appears is a lot of choice as for how one can construct the fiber product $X \times_Z Y$ - $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ can be chopped up into affines in many different ways, and I am not comfortable enough with gluing to reassure myself that the resulting fiber product is always the same.

I know this is kind of a pedantic question, but I would like some guidance please. This story is not as clear to me as I would like.

Comment: Your complaint applies not just to the tensor product, but to any universal construction, including any limit "functor". I think most people are satisfied with objects defined only up to canonical isomorphism, and are happy to treat that as a functor. A more technical resolution is to use the anafunctor, which I believe was developed to address exactly your objection. http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/anafunctor

Comment: So it is also acceptable to treat fiber products as a functor? In particular, when verifying that if $Y_i$ is a cover of $Y$ then $X \times_Z Y_i$ is a cover of $X \times_Z Y$ (a part of the construction of the existence of fiber products of schemes), is it acceptable to deal with the cocycle condition giving the gluing as a vacuous consequence of applying functor $X \times_Z \_$? Because that is what I really want to do.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're asking about affine covers and cocycle condition (maybe you could elaborate?), but I am completely sure that fibered product can safely be treated as a functor.

Comment: I would like to be able to show that (notation of the previous comment), I can glue together the spaces $X \times_Z Y_i$ using the gluing data given by the inclusions of $Y_i$ into $Y$ to form a space $W$, then glue the maps obtained by applying the "functor" $X \times_Z \_$ to the open inclusion $Y_i \to Y$, to get a map from $W$ to $X \times_Z Y$, and thus a map from $W$ to $Y$. Finally I want to verify (with a similar argument) that $W$ has the fiber product universal property, which would show that $W \cong X \times_Z Y$, or that $X \times_Z Y_i$ cover $X \times_Z Y$.

Comment: @AreaMan: The "functoriality" you want follows from the universal property of the fiber products $X\times_Z Y_i$, for _any_ choice of such objects satisfying the universal property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want an honest functor, you can simply *choose* any representative of the isomorphism class in question; it doesn't have to be "canonical".  That is, for every pair $(X,Y)$ of $Z$-schemes, you can *choose* some triple $(P_{X,Y},p_{X,Y},q_{X,Y})$ where $P_{X,Y}$ is a $Z$-scheme and $p_{X,Y}:P_{X,Y}\to X$ and $q_{X,Y}:P_{X,Y}\to Y$ are maps of $Z$-schemes which satisfy the definiton of a fiber product.  There is then a functor $F:Sch/Z\times Sch/Z\to Sch/Z$ which on objects is given by $F(X,Y)=P_{X,Y}$ and on maps is given as follows.  Given a pair of maps $f:X\to X'$ and $g:Y\to Y'$, the universal property of $P_{X',Y'}$ means that there is a unique map $h:P_{X,Y}\to P_{X',Y'}$ such that $p_{X',Y'}h=p_{X,Y}$ and $q_{X',Y'}h=q_{X,Y}$.  Define $F(f,g)=h$.  You can check that this definition really does preserve composition.

(In the argument you are trying to understand, instead of constructing this functor for all $X$ and $Y$ at once, you first construct it on the full subcategory of $Sch/Z\times Sch/Z$ in which both objects are affine, and then on the full subcategory on which at least one object is affine.)

In general, choosing such a triple $(P_{X,Y},p_{X,Y},q_{X,Y})$ simultaneously for every $X$ and $Y$ (in some arbitrary category) might require some form of the axiom of choice.  However, in many cases, there is a straightforward "canonical" choice you can make without the axiom of choice (like the "canonical" construction of tensor products you mentioned).  But even when there is no clear "canonical" way to do the construction, there are still usually tricks you can do with the Axiom of Regularity to get an explicitly defined functor within the framework of ZF set theory (in particular, you can do this for fiber products of schemes).  I can say more about these tricks if you're interested, but they involve some fairly technical details about axiomatic set theory.

Comment: I think I am satisfied with an appeal to the axiom of choice - I don't think I could make any progress towards the ideas I am interested in if I stopped believing in that. The universal property is also going to imply that any two choices of these functors are naturally isomorphic, right? (Is this what is meant by the statement that the fiber product is defined up to canonical isomorphism?)

Comment: Yes, any two are naturally isomorphic, and the natural isomorphism is unique if you require that it commute with the natural transformations given by the maps $p_{X,Y}$ and $q_{X,Y}$.  Being defined up to canonical isomorphism means that for any two such things, there is a unique isomorphism between them which is compatible with all the structure that is part of the definition (in this case, that extra structure is the two projection maps).

Comment: @EricWofsey Why must any two tensor product functors (chosen from equivalence classes using the axiom of choice) be naturally isomorphic here, but in the answer to another question, they don't have to be? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3316527/must-2-tensor-product-functors-be-naturally-isomorphic  Is it because in that other question, the author only defined the tensor product functor for objects, but not also for morphisms, so there was no guarantee of naturality? I would love to be able to believe that all choices are equivalent up to natural isomorphism and forget the issue.

Comment: @hasManyStupidQuestions: Right, you need the functor to be given on morphisms as described in my answer, not just on objects.

Answer (score 4):

The tensor product is defined up to canonical isomorphism, which is different from being defined up to isomorphism: there is a universal map $M\times N \to M\otimes N$ through which any bilinear map $M \times N \to R$ factors, and if you give one construction of the tensor product (e.g. generators and relations),  and I give another one (e.g.perhaps I universally add an extra generator for no reason and then add a relation that makes it 0), this universal property will pin down a canonical isomorphism between our constructions. As a result there is no ambiguity in writing the functor $A \otimes \_\_$, say.

Comment: I think I see your point now -  there is an natural isomorphism between any two choices of functors giving the tensor products.